# Before OOP, were data structure members left public?

Tags: object-oriented, data-structures, history

When a data structure (for example, a queue) is implemented using an OOP language, some members of the data structure need to be private (for example, the number of items in the queue).

A queue can also be implemented in a procedural language using a `struct` and a set of functions that operate on the `struct`. However, in a procedural language you can't make the members of a `struct` private. Were the members of a data structure implemented in a procedural language left public, or was there some trick to make them private?

Comment: *"some members of the data structure needs to be private"* There's a big difference between "probably should be" and "needs to be". Give me an OO language and I guarantee I can make a queue that works perfectly fine even with all its members and methods being public, as long as you don't go abusing all that freedom.

Comment: To put a different spin on what @8bittree said, having everything public is just fine if the people using your code are disciplined enough to stick to the interface you've set out.  The private member construct came about because of people who couldn't keep their noses out of where they don't belong.

Comment: `private` accessors are a bit more nuanced than that.  They serve as documentation to the user of your class that those members are "for internal use only."

Comment: Did you mean "before encapsulation became popular"? Encapsulation was quite popular before OO languages became popular.

Comment: Further, there are "Post-OO" languages without data structure member privacy (julia),
and no doubt post-OO languages with data structure member privacy (maybe one could argue F#)

Comment: @FrankHileman I think that is actually the core of the question: OP wants to know if encapsulation existed in procedural languages, before Simula/Smalltalk/C++

Comment: I am sorry in advance if this comes across as condescending, I don't mean it to be. You need to learn some other languages. Programming languages are not for machines to run, they *are for programmers to think in*. They necessarily shape the *way* you think. You simply wouldn't have this question if you'd spent any significant time working with JavaScript/Python/Ocaml/Clojure, even if you did Java all day at your day job. Other than one C++ open source project I work on (that's mostly C anyways) I haven't really used a language with access modifiers since college, and I haven't missed them.

Comment: @Jared Smith I didn't say in my question that it's extremely important for some members of a data structure to be private (or maybe I did unintentionally when I said: *"some members of the data structure needs to be private"*), I just meant that it's better for some members of a data structure to be private, for example, it's better to have the number of items variable in a queue data structure to be private so that you don't accidentally modify the variable directly (again, not extremely important for the variable to be private, but important nonetheless).

Comment: Before clothes, were all anatomical members exposed to the public? =P

Comment: @Christopher your analysis of my reading of your question is correct: when you said "some members... *need* to be private" (emphasis mine) I took it that way. If you really meant that it was *better*, well, I certainly don't disagree but my point still stands that there's more than one way to achieve the same result. Your question is a good one, and illustrates a good rationale for learning different languages even if they're not necessarily something you'd deploy to production at foocorp.

Comment: @JaredSmith These languages don't always use access modifiers, but most of them provide some way to provide encapsulation, for example with the use of closures. These are also not infrequently used.

Comment: @Cubic that was precisely my point. I would add to that list of examples immutable-by-default (a la clojure): how worried are you about encapsulation if someone you hand a value to can't change it out from under you? The OPs question literally makes no sense in the context of idiomatic use of that language.

Comment: @JaredSmith Encapsulation isn't just about prevention of _writing_ internal state; _reading_ internal state can wreak quite a lot of havoc as well (by leading to making assumptions that aren't guaranteed to hold in the future).

Comment: @Cubic good point, but in terms of what keeps library authors up at night I'd guess it's the former a whole lot more than the latter.

Comment: @JaredSmith I think there is plenty of Microsoft engineers worried about the former :)

Comment: Not really an answer but the way that I handle this in C is to put `typedef struct myclass_t myclass_t` in the header and then define `struct myclass_t` in the implementation. This allows pointers to `myclass_t` to be used from other modules/files (because pointers to incomplete types are allowed) but prevents access to its members. The downsides are that it is impossible to store or pass an instance of `myclass_t` on the stack (because it is incomplete) or to have public member variables without needing getters for everything (because the entire definition has to be either public or private).

Answer (score 140):

OOP did not invent encapsulation and is not synonymous with encapsulation. Many OOP languages do not have C++/Java style access modifiers. Many non-OOP languages have various techniques available to offer encapsulation.

One classic approach for encapsulation is **closures**, as used in **functional programming**. This is significantly older than OOP but is in a way equivalent. E.g. in JavaScript we might create an object like this:

```js
function Adder(x) {
  this.add = function add(y) {
    return x + y;
  }
}

var plus2 = new Adder(2);
plus2.add(7);  //=> 9
```

The above `plus2` object has no member that would allow direct access to `x` – it's entirely encapsulated. The `add()` method is a closure over the `x` variable.

The **C** language supports some kinds of encapsulation through its **header file** mechanism, particularly the **opaque pointer** technique. In C, it is possible to declare a struct name without defining its members. At that point no variable of the type of that struct can be used, but we can use pointers to that struct freely (because the size of a struct pointer is known at compile time). For example, consider this header file:

```c
#ifndef ADDER_H
#define ADDER_H

typedef struct AdderImpl *Adder;

Adder Adder_new(int x);
void Adder_free(Adder self);
int Adder_add(Adder self, int y);

#endif
```

We can now write code that uses this Adder interface, without having access to its fields, e.g.:

```c
Adder plus2 = Adder_new(2);
if (!plus2) abort();
printf("%d\n", Adder_add(plus2, 7));  /* => 9 */
Adder_free(plus2);
```

And here would be the totally encapsulated implementation details:

```c
#include "adder.h"

struct AdderImpl { int x; };

Adder Adder_new(int x) {
  Adder self = malloc(sizeof *self);
  if (!self) return NULL;
  self->x = x;
  return self;
}

void Adder_free(Adder self) {
  free(self);
}

int Adder_add(Adder self, int y) {
  return self->x + y;
}
```

There is also the class of **[modular programming languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_programming)**, which focuses on module-level interfaces. The ML language family incl. OCaml includes an interesting approach to modules called *functors*. OOP overshadowed and largely subsumed modular programming, yet many purported advantages of OOP are more about modularity than object orientation.

There's also the observation that classes in OOP languages like C++ or Java are often not used for *objects* (in the sense of entities that resolve operations through late binding/dynamic dispatch) but merely for *abstract data types* (where we define a public interface that hides internal implementation details). The paper *On Understanding Data Abstraction, Revisited* (Cook, 2009) discusses this difference in more detail.

But yes, many languages have no encapsulation mechanism whatsoever. In these languages, structure members are left public. At most, there would be a naming convention discouraging use. E.g. I think Pascal had no useful encapsulation mechanism.

Comment: See the error in `Adder self = malloc(sizeof(Adder));`? There's a reason typedef-ing pointers and `sizeof(TYPE)` is generally frowned upon.

Comment: @Deduplicator well spotted :D And thanks for your pointers (pun intended). I know this isn't absolutely idiomatic C code as written, but I wanted to keep the C reasonably close to the JS example.

Comment: You can't just write `sizeof(*Adder)`, because `*Adder` is not a type, just as `*int *` is not a type. The expression `T t = malloc(sizeof *t)` is both idiomatic and correct. See my edit.

Comment: Pascal had unit variables that could not be seen from outside that unit. Effectively the unit variables were equivalent to `private static` variables in Java. Likewise to C you could use opaque pointers to pass data in Pascal without declaring what it was. Classic MacOS used a lot of opaque pointers since public and private parts of a record (data structure) might be passed together. I remember Window Manager doing a lot of this since parts of the Window Record were public but some internal information was included as well.

Comment: Perhaps a better example than Pascal is Python, which supports object-orientation but no encapsulation, resorting to naming conventions such as `_private_member` and `output_property_`, or more advanced techniques for making imutable objects.

Comment: There's an annoying tendency in OOD literature to present every design principle as an *OO* design principle. The (non-academic) OOD literature tends to paint a picture of a "dark ages" where everyone was doing everything wrong, and then the OOP practitioners bring the light. As far as I can tell, this mostly derives from ignorance. For example, as far as I can tell, Bob Martin gave functional programming a serious look only a few years ago.

Comment: `plus2.add(0);` gives you access to `x` ;)

Comment: @EricDuminil Not really. It gives you a value that happens to equal the value of `x`, but it does not give you access to `x`.

Comment: @8bittree I'm pretty sure that was a joke – obviously the only properly encapsulated method is one that never returns! Asynchronous message passing for life!

Comment: @amon But... side channels... I think the only properly encapsulated method is one that never runs. Might even need to avoid existing at all.

Answer (score 31):

First, being procedural versus object oriented has nothing to do with public vs private. Plenty of object oriented languages have no notion of access control.

Secondly, in "C" - which most people would call procedural, and not object oriented, there are lots of tricks you can use to effectively make things private. A very common one is to use opaque (e.g. void*) pointers. Or - you can forward declare an object, and just not define it in a header file.

foo.h:

```
struct queue;
struct queue* makeQueue();
void add2Queue(struct queue* q, int value);
...
```

foo.c:

```
struct queue {
    int* head;
    int* head;
};
struct queue* makeQueue() { .... }
void add2Queue(struct queue* q, int value) { ... }
```

Look at the windows SDK! It uses HANDLE and UINT_PTR, and things like that to be generic handles to memory used in APIs - effectively making the implementations private.

Comment: I don't see any void pointers in your code.

Comment: My sample demonstrated a better (C) approach - using forward declared structs. to use the void* approach I would use typedefs:  In the .h file say typedef void* queue, and then everywhere we had struct queue just say queue; Then in the .c file, rename struct queue to struct queueImpl, and any arguments become queue (isntead of struct queue*) and the first line of code for each such function becomes struct queueImpl* qi = (struct queueImpl*)q

Comment: I don't really see how this makes anything private, though.

Comment: Hmm. It makes it private because you cannot access (read or write) any fields of the 'queue' from anyplace besides its implementation (foo.c file). What else did you mean by private? BTW - thats true for BOTH the typedef void* apporach and the (better) forward declare struct approach

Comment: OO languages without encapsulation? I think not. That was a fundamental component of smalltalk etc.

Comment: I must confess its been almost 40 years since I read the book on smalltalk-80, but I don't recall any notion of public or private data members. I think CLOS also had no such notion. Object Pascal had no such notion. I recall Simula did (probably where Stroustrup got the idea), and most OO languages since C++ have it. Anyhow - we agree encapsulation and private data are good ideas. Even the original questioner was clear on that point. He was just asking - how did oldies do encapsulation in pre-C++ languages.

Comment: @LewisPringle there is no mention of public data members in Smalltalk-80 because all "instance variables" (data members) are private, unless you use reflection. AFAIU Smalltalkers write an accessor for every variable they want to make public.

Comment: @LewisPringle by contrast, all Smalltalk "methods" (function members) are public (there are clumsy conventions for marking them private)

Comment: @dcorking thanks for the SmallTalk lesson/reminder ;-) My apologies...

Answer (score 13):

"Opaque data types" was a well-known concept when I did my computer science degree 30 years ago. We did not cover OOP as it was not in common usage at the time and "functional programming" was considered to be more correct.

Modula-2 had direct support for them, see https://www.modula2.org/reference/modules.php.

It has already been explained by Lewis Pringle how forward declaring a struct can be used in C. Unlike Module-2, a factory function had to be provided to create the object. ([Virtual methods were also easy to implement in C](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/GObject) by having the first member of a struct being a pointer to another struct that contained function pointers to the methods.)

Often convention was also used. For example, any field starting with “_” should not be accessed outside of the file that owned the data. This was easily enforced by the creation of custom checking tools.

Every large scale project I have worked on, (before I moved onto C++ then C#) had a system in place to prevent "private" data being accessed by the wrong code. It was just a little less standardized than it is now.

Answer (score 8):

Note there are many OO languages without a built-in ability to mark members private. This can be done by convention, without a need for the compiler to enforce privacy.  For example, people will often prefix private variables with an underscore.

There are techniques to make it harder to access "private" variables, the most common being the [PIMPL idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer#C). This puts your private variables in a separate struct, with just a pointer allocated in your public header files. This means an extra dereference and a cast to get any private variables, something like `((private_impl)(obj->private))->actual_value`, which gets annoying, so in practice is rarely used.

Answer (score 5):

Data structures didn't have "members", only data fields (assuming it was a record type). Visibility was typically set for the entire type. However, that may not be as limiting as you think, because the functions weren't part of the record.

Let's drop back and get a little bit of history here...

The dominant programming paradigm before OOP was called [structured programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured_programming). The initial main goal of this was to avoid use of unstructured jump statements ("goto"s). **This is a control flow oriented paradigm** (while OOP is more data-oriented), but it was still a natural extension of it to attempt to keep data logically structured just like the code.

Another outshoot of structured programming was [information hiding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_hiding), the idea that the implementations of the code's structure (which is likely to change fairly often) should be kept separate from the interface (which ideally won't change nearly as much). It's dogma now, but in the olden days, many people actually considered it better for every developer to get to know the details of the entire system, so this was at one time actually a controversial idea. The original edition of Brook's *[The Mythical Man Month](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mythical_Man-Month)* actually argued against information hiding.

Later programming languages designed explicitly to be good Structured Programming languages (for example, Modula-2 and Ada) generally included information hiding as a fundamental concept, built around some kind of concept of a cohesive facility of functions (and any types, constants, and objects they might required). In Modula-2 these were called "Modules", in Ada "Packages". A lot of modern OOP languages call the same concept "namespaces". These namespaces were the organizational foundation of development in these languages, and for most purposes could be used similarly to OOP classes (with no real support for inheritance, of course).

So in Modula-2 and Ada (83) you could declare any routine, type, constant, or object in a namespace private or public, but if you had a record type, there was no (easy) way to declare some record **fields** public and others private. Either your whole record is public, or it's not.

Comment: I spent quite a bit of time working in Ada.  Selective hiding (of part of a data type) was something we did all the time; in the containing package, you'd define the type itself as private or limited private; the package interface would expose public functions/procedures to get and/or set internal fields.  Those routines would of course need to take a parameter of the private type. I did not then and do not now consider this difficult.

Comment: Also, AFAIK most OO languages work the same way under the hood, i.e. myWidget.getFoo() is really implemented as getFoo(myWidget).  The `object.method()` invocation is just syntactic sugar.  Important IMHO -- see Meyer's Principle of Uniform Access / Reference -- but still just syntactic sugar.

Comment: @David - That was the Ada community's argument for years during the Ada 95 era. I believe they finally gave in and proved their own argument by allowing `object.method()` as an alternative form for `method(object, ...) ` for people who just couldn't make the conceptual leap.

Answer (score 0):

In C you could already pass around pointers to declared but undefined types as others have said, in effect restricting access to all fields.

You can also have private and public functions on a module-to-module basis. Functions declared static in the source file are not visible to the exterior, even if you attempt to guess their name. Similarly, you can have static file-level global variables, which is generally bad practice but allows isolation on a module basis.

It's probably important to stress that access restriction as a well standardized convention rather than a language-enforced construct works just fine (see Python). On top of that, restricting access to object fields is only ever going to protect the programmer when there is a need to change the value of the data inside an object after creation. Which is already a code smell. Arguably, C's and in particular C++'s `const` keyword for methods and function arguments is a far greater help to the programmer than Java's rather poor `final`.

Comment: The only feature C had that was specifically for information hiding was `static` global  data and operations (which meant they weren't presented to the linker for use from other compilations). You can plausibly argue any support C had for good software design practices aside from that was pretty much a hack, and not part of the original design of the language back in 1972.

Answer (score 0):

If your definition of *Public* is the ability to access implementation and data/properties via your own code at any point, the answer is simply: **Yes**. However, it was abstracted by diverse means - depending on the language.

I hope this succinctly answered your question.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a very simple counter-example: in Java, `interface`s define objects, but `class`es do not. A `class` defines an Abstract Data Type, not an object.

Ergo, any time you use `private` in a `class` in Java, you have an example of a data structure with private members that is not object-oriented.

Comment: This answer is of course technically correct, but it is totally incomprehensible to anyone who doesn't already know how what ADTs are and how they are different from objects.

Comment: I learned something from this answer.

Comment: Interfaces do _not_ "define" objects; they _specify contracts_ for operations/behaviors that objects _can do_ or perform. Just like inheritance is generally described by an _is a_ relationship and composition by a _has a_ relationship, interfaces are generally described by _can do_ relationships.